# How to randomly select an array out of several in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, jspsych

I have three arrays with 2 strings each, and would like to randomly select one of the arrays.

```
array1 = ["hello", "world"];
array2 = ["all", "good"];
array3 = ["bye", "now"];
```

Something like collecting the three arrays into one, and then math.random? I'm working with JsPsych, in case it is relevant

Comment: Add your arrays to another array, then use the answers from [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4550505/215552)

Answer (score 0):

To combine arrays with each other, you can use the method `contact()`.

For example :

```
var test1 = ['Emil', 'Tobias'];
var test2 = ['Arthur', 'Simon'];
var array = test1.concat(test2);
```

For generate a random value, read this topic : [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Thank you! Still, this is choosing strings form both variables at once eg. I'm getting Emil and Simon